# Removing leading zeros after joining with ( | ) pyspark

Tags: pyspark

How can I remove leading zeros after joining, for example,

```
100|0000000086,
200|000000000087,
100|00000075
300|00007505
```

I want this data to be

```
100|86,
200|87,
100|75,
300|7505
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to replace the leading zeros after `|`. In pyspark you can use `regex_replace` to achieve your desired result. For example,

```
df = df.withColumn('new_a', F.regexp_replace(F.col('a'), '\|0*', '|'))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|a                                                          |new_a                          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|100|0000000086, 200|000000000087, 100|00000075 300|00007505|100|86, 200|87, 100|75 300|7505|
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you! I am encountering an "invalid escape sequence '\|'" issue in, '\|0*', here. Maybe \\?

Comment: yeah you can try but I did not face that issue

Comment: Did you copy it properly? also is your target column of type string

Comment: Yes, they are string type columns

Comment: Could you put your code in question or a comment?

Comment: It worked out after adding an additional \ Thank you for your help :)